# How to find Zmin in point cloud within specific distance?

Tags: python, point-clouds, neighbours

Firstly, I need to find for each point in point cloud the neighboard points within 20 m in XY plane. After that from points within 20 m radius I need to find the Zmin and Zmax.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I get it done by using the  cKDTree.  It took around 7 min to process 10000 points. Since my point cloud is much larger is there something faster?